# Excel VBA Code Referencing Outlook Results in '287' Run Time Error in Office 2016

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel VBA script that references Outlook objects. This used to run in prior Office versions.

With Office 2016 and I am getting:

> Run-time error '287':
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Here is part of my code:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace

Dim Rec As Outlook.Recipient

Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressList

Set olApp = Outlook.Application

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olGAL = olNS.GetGlobalAddressList

Set Rec = olNS.CreateRecipient(Cells(1, 1))

Rec.Resolve
```

Cells(1,1) contains a valid email address.

The '287' error comes in on `Rec.Resolve`.

I have Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library checked in Tools/References.

I checked Trust Center Settings in Outlook under Programmatic Access. There are three radio button choices about suspicious activity handling which are all unchecked. My antivirus status is set to Valid.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you are dealing with a valid string (not empty) I'd suggest declaring a string variable:

```
Dim recipient as String 

Set recipient = Cells(1, 1)

MsgBox recipient

Set Rec = olNS.CreateRecipient(recipient)

Rec.Resolve
```

Nothing has been changed in the Office or Outlook PIAs. You just needed to replace the Outlook COM referece according to the Outlook version used on a system. The [Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your code (and changed Set recipient = to recipient =  ) but I still see the same errror. I am also noticing that when I type .Resolve, it gets changed to .resolve in the editor.    I have Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library checked in Tools/References.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `olApp`  variable.
replace the line

```
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
```

with

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  I made the change, but I am still getting the 287 error.  I have seen that error quite a bit in my attempts to understand the Outlook object structure, so I am thinking there is something basic I am missing.  Just not sure what that is yet.. hmm..

Comment: In this example, the '287' error comes in on "Rec.Resolve".

Comment: As a test, can you try to pass a hardcoded string to CreateRecipient?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried a hardcoded string, but it still gives me the 287 error.  Some have suggested this is a security issue. I checked Trust Center Settings in Outlook under Programmatic Access.  There are three radio button choices about suspicious activity handling which are all unchecked.  My antivirus status is set to Valid.